# Will Ashley ever forgive me?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are my romance options in ME3 limited if I cheated on my ME1 romance in ME2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53768/are-my-romance-options-in-me3-limited-if-i-cheated-on-my-me1-romance-in-me2)

So, in Mass Effect 1, I had a romantic relationship with Ashley (what can I say, blue just doesn't do it for me).  In Mass Effect 2, I left her in the dust and shacked up with Tali.

Is there any way in Mass Effect 3 for me to repair my relationship with Ashley?  Should I just pursue Tali again instead?  I haven't gotten to the point where she's a squad member yet, but I do understand I'll pick her up eventually.  Will either of these cause problems between the two of them?

(Alternate title: *I've got 99 problems, and a Quarian's one*)

Comment: This is pretty similar to: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53768/are-my-romance-options-in-me3-limited-if-i-cheated-on-my-me1-romance-in-me2

Comment: @agent86 - My search-fu is weak today because I was shocked I couldn't find anything else like this...although this is a bit different from that scenario because both characters in this example are still romanceable in ME3.  The answer there is pretty applicable, though, so now I'm unsure if I should leave this one be or not...