# Can you romance Liara if you'd already been with someone else in ME2?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are my romance options in ME3 limited if I cheated on my ME1 romance in ME2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53768/are-my-romance-options-in-me3-limited-if-i-cheated-on-my-me1-romance-in-me2)

I romanced Jack in 2. So can I break it off with her and romance Liara?