# Romancing Liara in Mass Effect 3

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-2, mass-effect

I romanced Liara in ME1 and the Lair of the Shadow Broker during Mass Effect 2. What would happen if I romanced someone else after the Lair of the Shadow Broker in ME2 in terms of ME3?

Comment: There are plenty of duplicates to this question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53768/are-my-romance-options-in-me3-limited-if-i-cheated-on-my-me1-romance-in-me2 and http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/62248/can-you-romance-liara-if-youd-already-been-with-someone-else-in-me2

Answer (score 4):

The person that you were last engaged in a romance with is taken on into Mass Effect 3, however I believe you only have one chance to romance someone per game (as the final romance "lock in" is just before/after going through the Omega relay).

Because you don't romance Liara (you just carry on the romance) during Lair of the Shadow Broker you can still only romance one "new" person from ME2 (by new, I mean start a new romance).

Hope that helps.

Comment: It seems strange, I finished LotSB early in mass effect 2 and romanced liara, but im still getting the option to romance tali and miranda, i tested it and tali did come up to shepards cabin so now im really confused! thanks for the advice anyway i suppose ill just have to trial rum it in mass effect 3

Comment: You'll always have the option to do the romance of each person, however you'll only have one shot at each, and you can only have one in the end. Most of them will tell you to pick if you have 2 or more romances running